# How can i change the orientation to landscape mode?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios7, landscape-portrait

I am new to iOS. I developed one application, in my View i have lot of objects are there. When i am changing the iPad to landscape mode, all objects positions are changing. I mean all objects height and width and positions are also changed so i am getting problem with it. Now, should i change every object resolution or is there any direct methods to solve this problem. Please send me the code. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement below:-

```
 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
CGRect bounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]; // portrait bounds
if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation])) {
    bounds.size = CGSizeMake(bounds.size.height, bounds.size.width);
}
        return YES
    }
```

Comment: I implemented that method but still my buttons, images and textFieds not in proper positions. Bonds changed. Some of them large size and some are small and some objects not showing in View i rotate the devide to Landscape

Comment: Have modified Please try now

Comment: Still i am facing same problem

Answer (score 0):

If you want to support multiple orientations then you can specify the layout(s) using the old "springs and struts" system or you can use Autolayout. For the beginning with iOS7, take a look at [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1).